# Accessing the returned XML from an API call

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have the following action method to perform an API call:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Rack rack, FormCollection formValues)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {

                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
                    foreach (string key in formValues)
                    {
                    query[key] = this.Request.Form[key];
                    }
                    query["username"] = "testuser";
                    query["password"] = ///.....
                    query["assetType"] = "Rack";
                    query["operation"] = "AddAsset";
                    var url = new UriBuilder("http://win-spdev:8400/servlets/AssetServlet");
                    url.Query = query.ToString();
                    try
                    {
                        string xml = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
                    }
```

The return XML from the API call looks as follow:-

```
<operation>
<operationstatus>Failure</operationstatus>
<message>Rack already exists.Unable to add</message>
</operation>
```

but how i can reach the message and operationstaus and according to them to display an appropriate message . i use to serialize the returned Json such as , but i am not sure how to do so for the xML:-

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var myObject = serializer.Deserialize<newprocess>(json);
                    string activityid = myObject.activityId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load it into an `XmlDocument`.

Untested and from the top of my head:

```
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(theXML);
    var status = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/operation/operationstatus").InnerText;
    var message = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/operation/message").InnerText;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but there is not method named LoadXML under the XmlDocument ?

Comment: @johnG It is an instance method. I've updated my answer. See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you using ASP.NET mvc, I believe you can use HttpClient, instead of WebClient:

Define result class:

```
   public class operation
   {
          public string operationstatus{get;set;}
          public string message{get;set;}              
   }
```

And then use it for automatic deserilization:

```
   var client = new HttpClient();
   var result = client.PostAsync(url, 
        new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>{
           {"username","testuser"},
           {"assetType","Rack"}}))
       .Result.Content
       .ReadAsAsync<operation>().Result;
```

Comment: Now that looks fancy! I have to remember that!

Comment: thanks or your reply and code, but what will be the benefits of using HttpClient instad of HttpWeb in my case?

Comment: @johnG Well, i don't think, that there is anything you can do with HttpClient, and can't do with WebClient. It just new class introduced in 4.5 and i a think it's syntax looks nicer and shorter. But it's really up to you